# C Makefile for 2 mainfiles

Tags: makefile

It's my first question around here. I'm working on a project for my course.
I know this question might have been answer to many times but I can't really understand what's the problem in the other people's topics.

The project is a simple chat with pipes and forks and I need to make a Makefile to compile the program. Here's my makefile:

```
CC=cc
FLAGS=-c -Wall
LIBS=-lm
OBS=cliente.o server.o

all : cliente server

cliente.c : cliente
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) cliente.c

server.c : server
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) server.c
```

And the output is:

```
make: Circular cliente.c <- cliente dependency dropped.
cc    -c -o cliente.o cliente.c
cc   cliente.o   -o cliente
make: Circular server.c <- server dependency dropped.
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you've got your rules backwards.  The correct syntax for `Makefile` rules is:

```
target-you-are-trying-to-build: things it depends on
        command to build target from things it depends on
```

Therefore, you want to write:

```
cliente : cliente.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) cliente.c

server: server.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) server.c
```

(Note the flipping of the executable and the source file in the first line of each rule.)

The reason your original `Makefile` works at all is because `make` has some built in rules, so when you type `make`, it tries to build `all` which needs `cliente` and `server`, and it generates automatic rules to build `cliente` from `cliente.c` and `server` from `server.c`.  (You can tell it's using it's internal rules and not yours because it ignores your `FLAGS`.)

The error messages about dropped dependencies are because you've told it to build `cliente`, which it knows it can build from `cliente.c`, but your rules tell it that `cliente.c` should be built from `cliente` which makes a circular dependency, so it complains.

**However**, as you note in the comment, this still won't work right.  That's because your rules for building `cliente` and `server` don't actually build `cliente` and `server`.  The command:

```
cc -c -Wall cliente.c
```

only compiles `cliente.c` to an object file `cliente.o` because of the `-c` flag.  It doesn't link or output an executable.  The modified version in @InvicibleWolf's answer which is equivalent to:

```
cc -c -Wall -o cliente -c client.c
```

won't work either, because the (multiple) `-c` flags produce object files, not executables, even if you force the output to go to `cliente` instead of the default of `cliente.o`.  You're getting a "permission denied" error because, by default, object files are created without execute permissions.  (Giving them execute permissions wouldn't help -- object files can't be run directly, so you'd get a different error.)

There are a couple of approaches here:

#### Use `make`'s built-in rules exclusively

The following `Makefile` will work:

```
CC=cc                 # should be "CC=", not "C="
CFLAGS=-Wall          # internal rules use CFLAGS not FLAGS, don't need -c
LDLIBS=-lm            # internal rules use LDLIBS not LIBS

all : cliente server

cliente: cliente.o

server: server.o
```

This tells makes that `cliente` can be built from `cliente.o`, and `make` is smart enough to generate a rule equivalent to:

```
cc cliente.o -lm -o cliente
```

using your definition of `CC` and `LDLIBS`.  It will also automatically generate the rule to build `cliente.o` from `cliente.c` without any guidance, equivalent to:

```
cc -Wall -c -o cliente.o cliente.c
```

using your definition of `CFLAGS`.  (It supplies the `-c` flags automatically.)

#### Use explicit rules that directly generate the executable from the C file

This will work, too.  It's just what @InvicibleWolf has written above with a typo fixed, the `-c` dropped, and the `LIBS` value included in the rules:

```
CC=cc             ## use CC=, not C=
FLAGS=-Wall       ## no -c flag
LIBS=-lm

all : cliente server

cliente: cliente.c
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIBS) -o cliente cliente.c    # no -c, and use LIBS

server: server.c
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(LIBS) -o server server.c      # no -c, and use LIBS
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for you're answer.
I've applied the changes you recommended and it doesnt compile now even tho it says that it did.
the output is: 
cc -c -Wall cliente.c
cc -c -Wall server.c

it appears everytime i compile(even if no changes were made in both files) but it doesnt compile

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer.  The culprit is the `-c` flag which is forcing creation of an object file (which can't be executed) instead of a linked executable.

Comment: After reading it carefully and considering your edit i've made it work. thank you so much and happy codding

Answer (score 0):

To compile your make file should follow the rule @K. A. Buhr mentioned in the answer. Makefile in his answer will just create object files . Considering your question I think you want to make two binaries client and server, so your make file should look like this:

```
C=cc
FLAGS= -Wall
LIBS=-lm
# OBS=cliente.o server.o not necessary if you are clreating to different binaries

all : cliente server

cliente: cliente.c
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o cliente cliente.c

server: server.c
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o server server.c
```

This will create object file as well as binaries too. -o option is to output to server/cliente file, and -c option means compile and assemble, but do not link or other words generate object files.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It appears that i'm now able to compile and now when im trying to excute (./server & ./cliente) it says that i dont have permissions!

Comment: you can do chmod +x file_name to add the execute permissions.

Comment: It appears that it solved the problem and another has appeared: cannot execute binary files: exec format error.

Im sorry that im asking stuff over stuff but i'm really confused about this.